# Temporarily, programmatically disable screen rotation in Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt

**Please note:** This question is about Qt C++ framework, not normal Java API. In Java, this question [has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6599770/607407).

In the main menu of my application, I really don't want to worry about different kinds of screen rotation. I would like to disable screen rotation until user goes to other views where screen rotation is meaningful. For main menu, I want to use portrait view only.

How to achieve that? How to control app screen rotation?

Comment: If I’m not mistaken (i.e., it was added to Qt in the last half year or so) you need use native API for that (as you want to do it at runtime). I wrote a small wrapper class for that in one my projects, to do this on Android and iOS.

Comment: possibly related: [Landscape mode in Qt-Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546117/landscape-mode-in-qt-android-application)

Comment: @pasbi Not really, the solution for permanent landscape mode was already known back in 2015 when I asked this question. But this question is about changing the mode to landscape temporarily, such as you would if you wanted to play a video on screen.

Comment: @TomášZato hm... I'm trying to lock the screen to landscape permanently and I'm facing the exactly same issues as described in the linked question/answer. I'd be happy with a dynamic solution as described here, too. So I guess from this point of view they are related (but certainly not a duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the orientation using

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QtAndroid::androidActivity();
activity.callMethod<void>("setRequestedOrientation", "(I)V", orientation);
```

where orientation is an `int` representing the orientation. You can copy  [the codes provided in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR) (e.g., `0` to lock landscape, `1` to lock portrait and `-1` to unlock any rotation), but I recommend to use, e.g.,

```
QAndroidJniObject::getStaticField<int>("android.content.pm.ActivityInfo", "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE");
```

to get the code values.

This answer is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/38947312/4248972. The difference is that this answer also explains how to unlock rotation again and provides a sample to show how to get the orientation codes without manual copying.