# Landscape mode in Qt-Android application

Tags: android, qt, qml, orientation

I created a Qt/QML application and ported the application to Android.
Now I'm able to run the application on the Android device.
I want to fix the orientation mode to Landscape.

I manually edited the `AndroidManifest.xml` and set the `android:screenOrientation="unspecified"` to `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"`

```
<activity
  android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
  android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity"
  android:label="Engage"
  android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
  android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Each time when I deploy the project, the manifest is overwritten and reset to `android:screenOrientation="unspecified"`

Comment: Did you clear before building? `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`as always worked for me and also `sensorLandscape` worked nice in a quick check.

Comment: Yes I cleared the build. Also when deploy the application it reset to 'unspecified'

Comment: possibly related: [Temporarily, programmatically disable screen rotation in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34310349/4248972)

Answer (score 3):

I got a solution for this.

Add a folder  in your project folder. I have named 'android-sources'.
Copy your `AndroidManifest.xml` from android-build and paste to 'android-sources' folder.
Open .pro file and add the following

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    android-sources/AndroidManifest.xml
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android-sources
```

Then open the `AndroidManifest.xml`

change the orientation

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

Comment: What the other answser says was exactly this, expected that you don't have to manually edit the pro....

Answer (score 1):

On [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/36613/solved-how-to-fix-screen-orientation-to-landscape-in-quick-2/4) the following solution is suggested:

Just go to the projects, running, click on details and create androidmanifest.xml, choose a directory. After that add it to your project if it didnt happen automatically and edit it. 4th line should look like this:

```
@<activity android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">@
```

just change "unspecified" to "sensorLandscape" and save it.

It won't be overwritten every time you deploy.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have done the same. It is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you, finally I found the solution for this question.
Follow these steps:

1. Select Projects > Build > Build Android APK > Create Templates.
2. Check the path in Android package source directory.
3. Select Copy the Gradle files to Android directory if you plan to
   extend the Java part of your Qt application
4. Select Finish to copy the template files to the android directory
   and to open the manifest file for editing.
5. In screen orientation field select "SensorLandscape".
   [image]